# In a list, how to pick whatever is not f and its derivatives?

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

Suppose I have a list like:

```
list1 = {{f[x], Sin[x]}, {f'[x]}, {f''[x]}};
list2 = {{f[x]}, {Cos[x], f''[x]}};
```

> [image]

I want to pick these lists and convert them to:

```
list1 = {{f[x], Framed[Sin[x]]}, {f'[x]}, {f''[x]}};
list2 = {{f[x]}, {Framed[Cos[x]], f''[x]}};
```

i.e. apply a listable function in these lists that return the list with a function such as `Framed[x]` applied in whatever functions are not `f` and its derivatives.

Comment: Very respectfully, but a member for 11 years posting an image instead of properly formatted code is not good for newer members...

Comment: @bmf I was going to post the code, but it gets a kinda unreadable. With lots of `[Prime]`, etc.

Comment: @bmf Done. $$$$

Comment: I had already done it for you. it's the code about the image. but thanks for taking the time to edit :-)

Comment: @bmf No, I need the f's.

Comment: could you show what each output should be for the two list examples you gave?

Comment: @Nasser It picks whatever is not f and it derivatives and delivers Framed[x], for example. In the second list, {{f[x]}, {Cos[x], f''[x]}} would get {{f[x]}, {Framed[Cos[x]], f''[x]}}.

Comment: To make it clear, could you edit your question and show by typing in what the output should be? This will be more clear for the readers I think than trying to just use words to describe the output. I do not know what Framed is in your comment above.

Comment: @bmf I guess I'm writing it poorly, second language, etc. I want to apply a function in `{{f[x]}, {Cos[x], f''[x]}}` that returns `{{f[x]}, {Framed[Cos[x]], f''[x]}}`, ie: It will apply `Framed` in all elements which are not f and it's derivatives.

Comment: I got it after I saw the example. I was trying to decipher the statement itself and I was getting confused

Answer (score 8):

**Using `Replace`:**

```
Replace[#
    , k : Except[f[__] | Derivative[_][f][_]] ->
     Framed[k
      , RoundingRadius -> 5
      , Background -> Yellow
      ], {2}
    ] & /@ {list1, list2} // Column
```

[image]

Now you can parse (read) this roughly as:

`Replace` from (level 2 only) of the following lists, the pattern `k` that consists of anything `Except` f[_] or any of its derivatives and `Frame` it with options.

Comment: (+1) Very nice, Indeed!

Answer (score 8):

```
h = Replace[#, b_?(FreeQ @ f) :> Highlighted[b], 2] &;


h @ list1
```

[image]

```
h @ list2
```

[image]

Comment: How can I enhance it and apply it like: `h = Replace[#, b_?(FreeQ[f]) :> Highlighted[b], All] ` so that it doesn't highlight the `x`'s?

Comment: I guess I found a way: `h = Replace[#, {x -> x, b_?(FreeQ[f]) :> Highlighted[b]}, All] &;`.

Comment: The trouble is that it doesn't work if we get more complicated expressions such as `list1 = {{f[x], Sin[x]}, {f'[x]}, {f''[x Cos[x]]}}`. It will highlight the `x Cos[x]`.

Answer (score 7):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

ClearAll["Global`*"]

list1 = {{f[x], Sin[x]}, {f'[x]}, {f''[x]}, {Sin[x], Cos[x]}};
list2 = {{f[x]}, {Cos[x], f''[x]}};

notf[x_List] := If[FreeQ[#, f], Framed[#], #] & /@ x

notf /@ list1
```

[image]

```
notf /@ list2
```

[image]

```
SetAttributes[notf2, Listable];

notf2[x_] := If[FreeQ[x, f], Framed[x], x]

notf2@list1
```

[image]

```
notf2@list2
```

[image]

Comment: This is really nice, I didn't know `FreeQ[].` I guess this will help me A LOT in future projects!

Answer (score 6):

Another way to do this is as follows:

```
notf = Internal`CopyListStructure[#, 
If[SameQ[Variables[Level[Head[#], {-1}]], {f}], #, Framed[#]] /@Flatten@#] &;
```

Test:

```
notf@list1
```

[image]

```
notf@list2
```

[image]

Just to remember an undocumented function! :-)

Answer (score 6):

Another way, thanks to the help I got from [how-to-use-position-to-select-based-on-absence-of-a-pattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/280550/how-to-use-position-to-select-based-on-absence-of-a-pattern)  which is to find positions of entries that do not have the patttern `f[_]` or the pattern for derivative of any order and then use `MapAt` to put a frame around the positions found.

```
list1 = {{f[x], Sin[x]}, {f'[x]}, {f''[x]}, {Sin[x], Cos[x]}};
list2 = {{f[x]}, {Cos[x], f''[x]}};
pattern = (FreeQ[#, Alternatives[f[_], Derivative[_][f][_]]] &);
p1 = Position[list1, _?pattern, {2}, Heads -> False];
```

And now

```
MapAt[Framed[#] &, list1, p1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
p2 = Position[list2, _?pattern, {2}, Heads -> False];
MapAt[Framed[#] &, list2, p2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
list1 = {{f[x], Sin[x]}, {f'[x]}, {f''[x]}};
list2 = {{f[x]}, {Cos[x], f''[x]}};

list1 /. f[x] -> Nothing /. Derivative[n_][f][x] -> Nothing // Flatten

(* {Sin[x]} *)


list2 /. f[x] -> Nothing /. Derivative[n_][f][x] -> Nothing // Flatten

(*   {Cos[x]}  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: I'll need the f's and it's derivatives. I just want to replace whatever is not f and it's derivatives by Framed[something_not_f_and_its_derivatives].

Comment: @Red Banan Look, that's opposite to what you initially wrote.