# How to use Position to select based on absence of a pattern?

Tags: pattern-matching, index

I need to use `Position` to obtain positions of entries in list of lists that do not contain a certain pattern.

The problem is that `Position` wants the pattern to find. Not the pattern to avoid.

Also `Position` does not take in a pure function, which one can use to do the checking and return True or False.

I do not know how to tell Position to look for entries that do not match a given pattern. Here is an example

```
lis = {{Tan[x], Exp[x]}, {3, x + Sin[x], 7}, {5, Cos[x], 99}}
```

I want to find positions of entries that *does not* contain the pattern `Sin[_]`

It is easy to find the position which contains the pattern

```
Position[lis, Sin[_]]
(* {{2, 2, 2}} *)
```

But how to do the opposite? `FreeQ` does not work. The thing that goes at the end has to be a pattern.

I am not looking for other functions such as Select and Cases. I need to use Position in order to obtain the actual positions to use with Extract for example.

I looked at [FunctionRepository/resources/SelectPositions](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/SelectPositions/) and even though this does allow one to use a function, it does not return Positions in same format `Position` command does.

Here is an example. Lets find entries with `Sin[_]` in it

```
lis = {{Tan[x], Exp[x]}, {3, x + Sin[x], 7}, {5, Cos[x], 99}}
foo = Not[FreeQ[#, Sin[_]]] &;
p = ResourceFunction["SelectPositions"][lis, foo]
(* {{2}} *)
```

Compare to

```
lis = {{Tan[x], Exp[x]}, {3, x + Sin[x], 7}, {5, Cos[x], 99}}
Position[lis, Sin[_]]

(* {{2, 2, 2}} *)
```

The question again is: I would like to use `Position` to specify not the pattern to find, but the pattern to avoid.

So it will return all those positions which do not have this pattern. For the above example those positions will be by inspection (assuming I did it right)

```
 {{1,1},{1,2},  {2,1},{2,2,1},{2,3},  {3,1},{3,2},{3,3} }
```

Any suggestions?

V 13.2

Comment: `pos = Position[lis, Except[Sin[_]], {2}, Heads -> False]` ?

Comment: @Syed I did not know I could use `Except[pattern]`. This looks promissing. I do not know why it returns `{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}}` instead of what I was expecting `{{1,1},{1,2},  {2,1},{2,2,1},{2,3},  {3,1},{3,2},{3,3} }` but this is not important now, will look at it more. But I think this should work if you like to make it an answer.  I think help for Position should had an example using `Except` !

Comment: `Position[lis, _?(Head[#] =!= Sin &)]` or `Position[lis, _?(FreeQ[#, Sin] &)]`

Comment: @BobHanlon thanks. But I need to specify a pattern. This was just an example, and to make it general, I'd like to use a pattern to **avoid**. Your's work if I am looking for entries that do not have `Sin`, but again, this was just an example. Except allows one to use a pattern inside, and I just did not know about it.

Comment: You can put any pattern that you want into the [`PatternTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html) including (as shown) those that contain pure functions.

Comment: @BobHanlon that is nice. I will look more at it. seems very useful. Too many functions, too little time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I understand it, `Except` is a pattern object and it fits with *pattern* matching.

```
lis = {{Tan[x], Exp[x]}, {3, x + Sin[x], 7}, {5, Cos[x], 99}}


pos = Position[lis, Except[Sin[_]], {2}, Heads -> False]
```

`FreeQ` is a function on the other hand and you can use the [PatternTest](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html) construct to use it to search for the lack of a pattern.

```
pos2 = Position[lis, _?(FreeQ[Sin[_]]), {2}, Heads -> False]
```

Moreover, `Position` will search through `Head` by default so you have to restrict that and search at the level required. You can experiment with these options further.

---

Result:

> {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}}

---

Regarding the pure function, the [PatternTest](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html) construct works; e.g.,

```
pos3 = Position[lis, _?(# > 2 &), {2}, Heads -> False]
```

> {{2, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {3, 3}}

```
Extract[lis, pos3]
```

> {3, 7, 5, 99}

Answer (score 1):

```
ps = Position[lis,x_/;Head[x]=!=Sin,{2},Heads->False]

(* {{1,1},{1,2},{2,1},{2,2},{2,3},{3,1},{3,2},{3,3}} *)
```